# TikZ picture size issue

Tags: tikz-styles, tikzscale

I'm trying to set 3 picture side by side and eventually set some caption on them, but for some reason the pictures are out of scale, specially the middle one. I don't know how to fix this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,on grid]
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=20pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Red) {Red};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP1) [below =of Red,] {ISP};
\node[draw,circle] (ISP2) [left =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw,circle] (ISP3) [right =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw, rounded rectangle ,minimum height=30pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Consumer) [below=of ISP1] {Usuarios};
\draw (Red)--(ISP1);
\draw (Red)--(ISP2);
\draw (Red)--(ISP3);
\draw (ISP1)--(Consumer);
\draw (ISP2)--(Consumer);
\draw (ISP3)--(Consumer);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,on grid]
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=20pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Red) {Red/ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP1) [below =of Red] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP3) [right =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=30pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Consumer) [below=of ISP1] {Usuarios};
\draw (Red)--(ISP1);
\draw (Red)--(ISP3);
\draw (ISP1)--(Consumer);
\draw (ISP3)--(Consumer);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-30pt}] (Red)--(Consumer);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,on grid]
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=20pt ,minimum width=100pt,rotate=90] (Red) {\rotatebox{270}{Red}};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP1) [right =of Red] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP2) [above =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP3) [below =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (Consumer) [left=70pt of Red] {Usuarios};
\draw (ISP1)--(Red);
\draw (ISP2)--(Red);
\draw (ISP3)--(Red);
\draw (Red)--(Consumer);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! What do you mean by "out of scale"? You've specifically resized them so that all have the same width with `\resizebox`. If they didn't all have the same width before resizing, then naturally the font sizes are different.

Comment: Thanks Torbjon, then its a font size issue?, even tho I haven't specified anything different in the 3 pictures?.

Comment: No, the problem is that you scale the three different pictures by different amounts, because they don't have the same width initially, but you scale all to the same width.

Comment: Oh..., I get it now what is happening, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use three separate `tikzpictures` here. You can shift the second and third part right using a `scope` environment with `xshift` (and `yshift`) in the options. Some adjustment of the `node distance` and other things are needed to make it fit in the textblock of a standard `article`.

Your problem occurs because the three diagrams have different widths initially, but then you scale them all to the same width. Hence, the scaling factors are different in each case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1.2cm,
  on grid,
  every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}
]
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=20pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Red) {Red};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP1) [below =of Red,] {ISP};
\node[draw,circle] (ISP2) [left =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw,circle] (ISP3) [right =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw, rounded rectangle ,minimum height=30pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Consumer) [below=of ISP1] {Usuarios};
\draw (Red)--(ISP1);
\draw (Red)--(ISP2);
\draw (Red)--(ISP3);
\draw (ISP1)--(Consumer);
\draw (ISP2)--(Consumer);
\draw (ISP3)--(Consumer);


\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=20pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Red) {Red/ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP1) [below =of Red] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP3) [right =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=30pt ,minimum width=100pt] (Consumer) [below=of ISP1] {Usuarios};
\draw (Red)--(ISP1);
\draw (Red)--(ISP3);
\draw (ISP1)--(Consumer);
\draw (ISP3)--(Consumer);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-30pt}] (Red)--(Consumer);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=8.7cm,yshift=-1.2cm]
\node[draw,rounded rectangle ,minimum height=20pt ,minimum width=100pt,rotate=90] (Red) {\rotatebox{270}{Red}};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP1) [right =of Red] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP2) [above =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (ISP3) [below =of ISP1] {ISP};
\node[draw, circle] (Consumer) [left=50pt of Red] {Usuarios};
\draw (ISP1)--(Red);
\draw (ISP2)--(Red);
\draw (ISP3)--(Red);
\draw (Red)--(Consumer);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```